# Adding div directly into ModelForm in django

Tags: django

Is there way to add div tag directly into ModelForm in django?

I want to get something like this:

```
<input></input>
<input></input>
.
.
<div class="someClass">
    <input></input>
<div>
<input></input>
```

Or i need to do this in html page?

### UPDATE

This is generated by:

```
{% for field in formFields %}
    {{field}}
{% endfor %}
```

I want for some inputs to be div around it.

Comment: How do you generate double `<input>`?

Comment: What do you mean? I will update my question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add div in your for loop like this:

```
{% for field in formFields %}
    {% if field.name == 'xxx' %}
    <div class="someClass">{{ field }}</div>
    {% else %}
    {{ field }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I thought so... Thanks.